# PHP: file_get_contents('php://input') returning string for JSON message

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read in a JSON message in my PHP app and this is my php code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $obj->{'S3URL'};
```

When I do this I am getting the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in setImage.php on line 25 (line 25 is the echo $obj->{'S3URL'}; line)
```

This is the request body of the request to the page:

```
Request Url: http://localhost:8888/setImage.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Params: {
   "S3URL": "http://url.com"
}
```

This is the request headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: chrome-extension: //rest-console-id
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
```

However, if I instead echo out the `$json` variable I get the following:

```
S3URL=http%3A%2F%2Furl.com
```

So it looks like `file_get_contents('php://input');` is reading it in as a string, and not as JSON, which will make parsing it more difficult.

Any idea why it isn't being returned as JSON, or how I can get it to be returned as JSON?

Comment: json_decode($json, TRUE); returns array not object.

Comment: 'php://input' always fetches the request body as-is. Therefore, if you don'T get JSON code, no JSON code was sent. Period. As there is an `=` in the string what you get, the form was most likely sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Abhik, yeah, I tried removing the TRUE, but still no dice. Thanks Johannes H, I am using the REST Console for sending the data, and from the content headers of the request it looks like it should be sending it as JSON, but maybe it isn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of `json_decode` is creating an associative array, not an object. You can treat it like an array, instead of an object. If you want an object, use this, instead:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

[See the documentation](https://www.php.net/json_decode) on the second parameter to `json_decode()`:

> assoc
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Also, as Johannes H. pointed out in the comments, the output of `echo $json;` indicates that you are not actually receiving JSON, in the first place, so you will need to address that, as well. You asked why it isn't JSON; without seeing how you are requesting this script, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: While correct, this isn't the only issue in the code. If `echo $json;` outputs `S3URL=http%3A%2F%2Furl.com` as stated in the question, no JSON was sent in the first place.

Comment: Right, even removing the "TRUE" hasn't solved the problem. I think Johannes is correct here.

Answer (score 7):

there are two type for executing this type of request

First : you can use it as an stdClassObject for this

**$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));**

it will return a object and you can retrieve data from this like

**$name = $data->name;**

Second : you can use it as an array for this

**$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);**

it will return a object and you can retrieve data from this like

**$name = $data['name'];**

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be form php://input (is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body).
change some setting from php.ini , try to make "allow_url_fopen" on.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one result will

```
$chd = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$childs = implode("",$chd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801419/7378998

It works for JSON or jquery post

```
$.post(url, $('form').serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript to send JSON, to a php file

send_recieve.js

```
var myObject = JSON.stringify({"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://localhost/dashboard/iwplab/j-comp/receive_send.php",false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4){console.log("xhr response:"+xhr.response)}
    alert(xhr.responseText);
 };
 xhr.send(myObject);
```

recieve_send.php

```
<?php
    $var = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    echo "Data recieved by PHP file.\n";
    if ($var["name"]=="John"){
        echo "a";
    }
    else{
        echo "b";
    }
    //Manipulate/validate/store/retrieve to database here
    //echo statements work as response
    echo "\nSent";

?>
```

echo statements work as a response.

Answer (score -1):

$obj = json_decode($json);

Just remove the true