# PHP: Getting 2 warning & 6 notices

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need help with 2 warnings and 6 notices.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 11
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 28
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 29
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 30
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 31
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>    on line 33
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'steamID' cannot be null in
>    on line 34

I'm been trying to fix code for like 4 hours now and I just can't understand what the hell is going on...

```
<?php
require_once "../config.php";
require_once "../db.php";
if(!isset($_GET['secret']) || $_GET['secret'] != $config['bot_key_add']){
    die("Access denied");
    return;
}

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

if((int)$json->userID ==)       
    return;

$weapon = urlencode($json->weapon);
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$weapon;
$steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
$item_price = json_decode($steam_price, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
if(empty($item_price) || $item_price->success == false || empty($item_price->median_price))
{
    $price = 400;
}
else 
{
    $price = $item_price->median_price;
    $price = str_replace("&#36;" , "", $price);
    $price = str_replace("$" , "", $price);
    $price = round(str_replace(",",".",$price), 2);
}
$saveWeapon = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$config['db_prefix']}users_items` (`steamID`, `classid`, `assetid`, `weapon_name`, `price`, `float`) VALUES (:steamId , :classid , :assetid , :weaponName , :price, :float)");

$saveWeapon->execute([  ":steamId"      => $json->userID,
                        ":classid"      => $json->classid,
                        ":assetid"      => $json->assetid,
                        ":weaponName"   => $json->weapon,
                        ":price"        => $price,
                        ":float"        => $json->color
]);
?>
```

Comment: You should post your warnings here, not link to an image of it.

Comment: Looks like `json_decode` returns array and not object but you are trying to access the properties as objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974951/php-file-get-contentsphp-input-returning-string-for-json-message 
Can you update the question with the output of `var_dump($json)` ?

Comment: $json = NULL /3chars

Comment: `(int)$json->userID ==)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your file_get_contents("php://input") doesnt return a file object, so rest is failing (all the warnings) due to missing file object. So "file_get_contents" can't open the correct file and steam is answering with error. Rest is a follow up error.

You can avoid this by checking and sanitizing the input to your script and abort if check fail.

Comment: Thank You, Then I just have to start "bot" to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your json decode is failing. The lines where you're getting the Notices are where you're trying to treat $json as an object.

Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php , when json decode fails it returns null, which you can't treat as an object.

I suggest sticking some error checking after the json decode, with  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

```
if($json === null) {
    throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

Note that if you're on php prior to 5.5.0, you'll need to define that function (from that function reference)

```
if (!function_exists('json_last_error_msg')) {
    function json_last_error_msg() {
        static $ERRORS = array(
            JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error',
            JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',
            JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'State mismatch (invalid or malformed JSON)',
            JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
            JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
            JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
        );

        $error = json_last_error();
        return isset($ERRORS[$error]) ? $ERRORS[$error] : 'Unknown error';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 400 Bad Request while try to file_get_contents():

```
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$weapon;
$steam_price = file_get_contents($link);
```

And then you try to json_decode this response and your $item_price will be null.
Second warning because your INSERT try to add row with all null fields but steamID cannot be null