# "php://input" returning string for json ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a string from `file_get_contents('php://input')`. I tried `json_decode()`, but the string is not a json. Here is the ajax request and the php code. How can I get the json sent from the ajax request and turn it into a php array?

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
echo $data;
```

Output:

```
string(7) "id=myId"
"id=myId"
```

Ajax(Includes Jquery):

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "myFile.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "contentType": "Json",
    "data": {"id": "myId"},
}).done(function(data, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
        console.log(data);
    }
}).fail(function(data, status, error) {
    throw new Error(error);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
});
```

Edit: `json_encode()` is returning null, so I cannot use the answer from this question: [PHP: file_get_contents('php://input') returning string for JSON message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974951/php-file-get-contentsphp-input-returning-string-for-json-message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: file\_get\_contents('php://input') returning string for JSON message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974951/php-file-get-contentsphp-input-returning-string-for-json-message)

Comment: It's form-encoded. You *could* decode it yourself, or just access it via `$_POST['id']` where PHP has already decoded it.

Comment: `$_POST["data"]` and `$_POST["id"]` didn't work for me, so I was forced to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` which did the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Sammitch mentioned in his comment, your current code is sending it with form encoding. For what you want, stringify the data before sending it to the server, so that it gets received as JSON. Modify your call to be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "myFile.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "data": JSON.stringify({"id": "myId"}),
})
```

This should result in the input being a json encoded object.

Comment: Looks like my problem was on the client side, not server side. Now after doing this, `json_encode()` is working!