# Why i am getting trying to get property of non-object error in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS , i want to insert data from form to MySQL database table ( in my case table name is employe ) But when i hit submit it is not inserting . I compiled insert.php file in browser which gives me this error ***"Trying to get property of non-object"*** . I am sending data in JSON format and then i have decoded in the `index.php` file but when i tried to access the decoded data via `$data` object it gives me the mentioned error .

**myApp.js code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.insertData = function(){
        $http.post("insert.php",{'name': $scope.name,'fname': $scope.fname,'dept': $scope.dept})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
           console.log("Inserted Successfuly!"); 
        });
    }
});
```

**insert.php code**

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$name = $data->name;
$fname = $data->fname;
$dept = $data->dept;

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'company';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO employe ('id','ename','fname','dept') VALUES('','$name','$fname','$dept')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
}
?>
```

**index.html code**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <title> Using Angular with PHP! </title>
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>-->
        <style type="text/css" src="css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
    </head>

    <body>   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="myController">
                    <form>
                        Your Name:   <input type="text" ng-model="name" /><br><br>
                        Father Name: <input type="text" ng-model="fname" /><br><br>
                        Department : <input type="text" ng-model="dept" /><br><br>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertData()" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 


       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: " I am sending data in JSON format" - but you are not. Try `var_dump($_POST);` and you will see what is actually being received.

Comment: @rjdown so what does this "$http.post("insert.php", " Line do ? I dumped the $_POST it printed out "array(0) { }" i didn't got that .

Comment: have you tried to print out `file_get_contents("php://input")` and see if it contains any data?

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 yes it returns string(0) ""

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146984/file-get-contentsphp-input-always-returns-an-empty-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will laugh but just by adding these `` around your table name would do your work fine

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO `employe`(`id`, `ename`, `fname`, `dept`) VALUES('','$name','$fname','$dept')";
```