# Why is posting JSON with PHP Curl not working?

Tags: php, json, curl, post

I have the following function:

```
function postCurl($url, $data){
    $data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init( $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
        
        return $result;
}
```

This function converts a (multidimensional) array to JSON should post it with curl.

The requested url simply returns all post values with:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),1).'</pre>';
```

I verified with Postman that the requested url is working but when I post via curl I get no result.
The only way I could replicate this issue with Postmanwas sending incorrect JSON so I bypassed the `json_encode` function and tried a valid JSON string but no result.

I got this function working in the past so I think it must be an issue with the settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `$data`?

Comment: It is a long string of JSON but as I mentioned in the question I bypassed the json_encode with something like: $data = '{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}'; So I don't think the ouput of $data is the problem.

Comment: So is there a HTTP response?

Comment: Yes, the function returns the content of the url but no post values

Comment: Why do you specify the content type `application/json` when you want to send a POST? You'd have to use the appropriate content type (one of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data" or "text/plain"), or the server won't accept the data.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with help from this link:

[file_get_contents('php://input') always returns an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146984/file-get-contentsphp-input-always-returns-an-empty-string)

Because I used `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );` I could not see that there was a redirect from [www.url.com](http://www.url.com) to url.com.

When a request is redirected you lose all data in `file_get_contents("php://input")`